# Does the collection constructor function for MongoDB only create a collection if it doesn't already exist?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

In Meteor, at the top of a scripts.js file:

```
PlayersList = new Mongo.Collection('players');
```

This code runs every time the script runs? I'm assuming that the collection will only be created if it doesn't already exist. Otherwise, the documents would be overwritten with empty ones?

Is this how it works?
What exactly does this line do when the specified collection already exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line does nothing with database, it only creates javascript object, which helps you to deal with collection. For example you can find players like that:

```
var single_player = PlayersList.findOne({
     name: {$regex: /john/}
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I was confusing this with the insert function. So I guess the collection is only created once we create a document inside it.

Comment: Yes, collections are created on first insert;) glad it helped